# mysql using user-defined variable in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, where-clause, user-defined

sql query:

```
select
    u.username,
        @total_subscribers:=(
            select count(s.id)
                from subscribers as s
                where s.suid = u.uid
        ) as total_subscribers
from users as u
where @total_subscribers > 0
```

if i remove `where @total_subscribers > 0` query will show all users and their total subscribers

but i want to show only those users who have at least 1 subscriber... after i add the where clause and use the defined variable i get an empty result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `group by` and `having`:

```
select
   u.username,
   count(s.id) as total_subscribers
from users as u
inner join subscribers as s on s.suid = u.uid
group by u.id
having count(s.id) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`MySQL` does not guarantee the order of evaluation of the session variables in this case.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html):

> The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and may change based on the elements contained within a given statement; in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between releases of the `MySQL` Server

Use this:

```
SELECT  u.*, COUNT(*)
FROM    users u
JOIN    subscribers s
ON      s.suid = u.uid
GROUP BY
        u.uid
```

The `JOIN` makes sure you have at least one subscriber.